# Positive definiteness of a bilinear form implies symmetry?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, bilinear-form

In the Wikipeda article about positive definite bilinear forms, there is the line

> It turns out that the matrix $M$ is positive definite if and only if it is symmetric and its quadratic form is a strictly convex function.

What does it mean a *strictly convex function*? Is it strictly convex on every convex subset?

Comment: You can find the definition of a strictly convex function on the corresponding [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition).

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is positive definite then Sylvester theorem says that $M$ has only positive eigenvalues and its quadratic form is the following:

$$q(x_1,..,x_n)=\lambda_1x_1^2+...+\lambda_nx_m^2$$ where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues.

So the function is strictly convex since the Jacobian matrix for the function $q:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $2M$ which is positive definite by assumption.